# Shader to distort texture by shape map

Tags: glsl, 2d, shader, webgl, distortion

I do not have enough knowledge.
What methods can be used to solve this problem.

For example from another [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/125408/how-to-distort-an-image-inside-a-shape): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vazHJ.jpg)

In fact, my task is a little easier. Because the map looks different:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxk90.jpg)

In my head I see such a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6UBT.jpg)

However, I do not have a scientific degree in trigonometry or sufficient experience with graphics to understand what I need to solve.

Please tell me what methodologies should I study to understand this?

The ready-made solution is also interesting if you attach the theoretical part to the solution.

Comment: @Mugen87 Why are you remove three.js tag?

Comment: Because your question is unrelated to the three.js API.

Comment: @Mugen87 Okay. I will add the GLSL tag, which in turn can be used in Three.js